# Draw striped open region in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would need to stripe a region between a curve and the rest of the space (the region is open). Is there any **pre-defined** function on MATLAB that does the trick?

Comment: @gnovice The supposed duplicate points to a closed question. Is that right?

Comment: @JJMDriessen It's a closed question but it has an accepted answer.

Comment: @JJMDriessen: Yes, I'm not sure why the duplicate was closed as unclear, since it seems fairly straightforward, and has a couple answers as well. It maybe wasn't the best written question, but probably deserves to be reopened.

Comment: I edited the question so that it hasn't been answered yet. Please, remove the duplicate tag. Thanks

Comment: There is no predefined function. That's why we pointed you to the duplicate.